# Trouble while compiling C code

Tags: c, compiler-errors, kernel, cross-compiling

I am trying to write a kernel from scratch using C and Assembly. Everything is working fine but this piece of code (the keyboard driver), gives me an getting an error each time I compile it, therefore I can't use the keyboard to test the rest of the kernel.
Here is the code:

```
#include "keyboard.h"
#include "../cpu/ports.h"
#include "../cpu/isr.h"
#include "screen.h"
#include "../libc/string.h"
#include "../libc/function.h"
#include "../fenix/kernel/kernel.h"
#include <stdint.h>

#define BACKSPACE 0x0E
#define ENTER 0x1C

static char key_buffer[256];

#define SC_MAX 57
const char *sc_name[] = { "ERROR", "Esc", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
    "7", "8", "9", "0", "-", "=", "Backspace", "Tab", "Q", "W", "E",
        "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P", "[", "]", "Enter", "Lctrl",
        "A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", ";", "'", "`",
        "LShift", "\\", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", ",", ".",
        "/", "RShift", "Keypad *", "LAlt", "Spacebar"};
const char sc_ascii[] = { '?', '?', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
    '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '=', '?', '?', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y',
        'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[', ']', '?', '?', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G',
        'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ';', '\'', '`', '?', '\\', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V',
        'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/', '?', '?', '?', ' '};

static void keyboard_callback(registers_t *regs) {
    /* The PIC leaves us the scancode in port 0x60 */
    uint8_t scancode = port_byte_in(0x60);

    if (scancode > SC_MAX) return;
    if (scancode == BACKSPACE) {
        backspace(key_buffer);
        kprint_backspace();
    } else if (scancode == ENTER) {
        kprint("\n");
        user_input(key_buffer); /* kernel-controlled function */
        key_buffer[0] = '\0';
    } else {
        char letter = sc_ascii[(int)scancode];
        /* Remember that kprint only accepts char[] */
        char str[2] = {letter, '\0'};
        append(key_buffer, letter);
        kprint(str);
    }
    UNUSED(regs);
}

void init_keyboard() {
   register_interrupt_handler(IRQ1, keyboard_callback);
}
```

And here is the build log (or something like that):

```
nasm boot/arch/x86/bootsect.asm -f bin -o boot/arch/x86/bootsect.bin
nasm boot/arch/x86/kernel_entry.asm -f elf -o boot/arch/x86/kernel_entry.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c fenix/kernel/kernel.c -o fenix/kernel/kernel.o
nasm cpu/interrupt.asm -f elf -o cpu/interrupt.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c drivers/keyboard.c -o drivers/keyboard.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c drivers/screen.c -o drivers/screen.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c cpu/idt.c -o cpu/idt.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c cpu/isr.c -o cpu/isr.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c cpu/ports.c -o cpu/ports.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c cpu/timer.c -o cpu/timer.o
cpu/timer.c: In function 'timer_callback':
cpu/timer.c:15:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'int_to_ascii' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     int_to_ascii(tick, tick_ascii);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
cpu/timer.c:10:40: warning: unused parameter 'regs' [-Wunused-parameter]
 static void timer_callback(registers_t regs) {
                                        ^~~~
cpu/timer.c: In function 'init_timer':
cpu/timer.c:22:38: warning: passing argument 2 of 'register_interrupt_handler' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     register_interrupt_handler(IRQ0, timer_callback);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from cpu/timer.c:6:0:
cpu/isr.h:93:6: note: expected 'isr_t {aka void (*)(struct <anonymous> *)}' but argument is of type 'void (*)(registers_t) {aka void (*)(struct <anonymous>)}'
 void register_interrupt_handler(uint8_t n, isr_t handler);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cpu/timer.c:29:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'port_byte_out' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     port_byte_out(0x43, 0x36); /* Command port */
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c libc/mem.c -o libc/mem.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/bin/i386-elf-gcc -g -ffreestanding -Wall -Wextra -fno-exceptions -m32 -c libc/string.c -o libc/string.o
/Users/JacoboSoffer/i386elfgcc/i386-elf/bin/ld  -o kernel.bin -Ttext 0x1000 boot/arch/x86/kernel_entry.o fenix/kernel/kernel.o cpu/interrupt.o drivers/keyboard.o drivers/screen.o cpu/idt.o cpu/isr.o cpu/ports.o cpu/timer.o libc/mem.o libc/string.o --oformat binary
drivers/keyboard.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `sc_name'
fenix/kernel/kernel.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
drivers/keyboard.o:(.rodata+0xc0): multiple definition of `sc_ascii'
fenix/kernel/kernel.o:(.rodata+0xc0): first defined here
drivers/keyboard.o: In function `init_keyboard':
/Users/JacoboSoffer/Desktop/Elemental/fenix copy/drivers/keyboard.c:50: multiple definition of `init_keyboard'
fenix/kernel/kernel.o:/Users/JacoboSoffer/Desktop/Elemental/fenix copy/fenix/kernel/../../drivers/keyboard.c:50: first defined here
make: *** [kernel.bin] Error 1
```

I am using macOS Sierra for this project, I am using a Cross Compiler targeting the i386-elf platform containing the programs of GCC and Binutils. Please help me I am stuck (and sorry if the question is a little nooby, I am new here).

Comment: Do you have duplicate definitions for these constants and functions in your kernel.c file? Or are you accidentally #including the .c, instead of the .h?

Comment: Sidenote: Any reason you don't make `sc_name` `const` qualified?

Comment: Which header declares `int_to_ascii()`?  Why didn't you include the header before using the function?  Similarly with `port_byte_out()`?  It's going to take a bit longer to work out what your function pointer problem is, but you're passing the wrong type to `register_interrupt_handler()`.

Comment: The pointer-to-function problem is modestly complex to describe; the compiler does its best, but comes up with a message that can easily cause confusion.  The `register_interrupt_handler()` function expects an `'isr_t {aka void (*)(struct <anonymous> *)}'` as its second argument.  You are going to need to track down what that type is, but it is _not_ `registers_t` because the compiler complains `'void (*)(registers_t) {aka void (*)(struct <anonymous>)}'`.  And while both 'aka' messages say the same thing, for the compiler to be complaining, they must actually be different types.

Comment: So, you need to change the definition of `timer_callback()` so that it expects whatever argument type an `isr_t` expects, which is not `registers_t`.  Interestingly, your callback doesn't use the argument it is passed — that might be a problem too.

Comment: At https://github.com/sukwon0709/osdev/blob/master/tutorial/src/isr.h (and https://github.com/sukwon0709/osdev/blob/master/tutorial/src/isr.h), I found _`typedef struct registers
{
 u32int ds;
 u32int edi, esi, ebp, esp, ebx, edx, ecx, eax;
 u32int int_no, err_code;
 u32int eip, cs, eflags, useresp, ss;
} registers_t;

typedef void (*isr_t)(registers_t);
void register_interrupt_handler(u8int n, isr_t handler);`_ which is similar to yours, but it isn't the same code — the type here is `struct registers` and not an anonymous structure type.  OTOH, there is a strong family resemblance.

Comment: You need to show us where you're getting `registers_t` and `isr_t` from.  There seems to be an issue there. If the types are in your own code, give the structure types a tag.  If they're not in your own code, we probably need to see what's defined.  Don't try defining types in a prototype's argument list; the type has prototype scope and can't be used anywhere else (including the function definition, which makes life tricky).

Comment: Thank you all, I solved the problem, turns out it was an error in another file.